# Windows Phone 8 Json get result number

Tags: windows-phone-8

[image]

I am creating WIndows Phone 8 News App, i wan to insert different data between Listbox like

```
if (result == 1){
    Display Header with first item from Json
}else{
    Display Listbox From Secound Json data
}
```

this is my code

```
 public void getMainData()
        {

            string jsonUrl = "http://Domian.com/api.json";

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(jsonUrl ));
           }


        void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string result = e.Result.ToString();
                JsonConvert.PopulateObject(result, PopulateData);
                NewsList.ItemsSource = PopulateData;           
            }
```

Please i am new to C# can some one help me please
Thank you very much

Comment: So you want the first item to have a different template?

Comment: Yes. and first data for header and Listbox start wirh secound data. i used Telerik RadDataBoundListBox and ListHeaderContent

Comment: Ok. Can you set a ListHeaderTemplate maybe?

Comment: every things is fine  code also working,  but  first (Header Data) and secound data is same now,  just i want  Listbox start with secount data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public void getMainData()
{
    string jsonUrl = "http://Domian.com/api.json";

    var result = (new HttpClient()).GetStringAsync(jsonUrl);
    var data = JsonConvert.DeseralizeObject(result);

    for(int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
    {
        if(i % 3 == 0)
        {
            // add banner
            var bannerGrid = new Grid();

            NewsList.Items.Add(bannerGrid);
        }

        // add the news
        var itemGrid = new Grid();
        itemGrid.Children.Add(new TextBox()
        {
            Text = data[i];
        });
        NewsList.Items.Add(itemGrid);
    }    
}
```

**The code above might not compile.** I wrote it in Notepad++. But you should understand how it works.

*The code is using HttpClient. It is available at NuGet.*

Comment: thank you very much,  i inserted header image and title but header and Listbox first item same with header.  if == 0  display first item else  display Listbox start with Secound item i want. how is it possible

Comment: @kakkuk can you add that to your question above and phrase it a little bit better?

Comment: i edited and inserted sample photo. thank you very much